# node js call selenium function and force the client side to open a browser on server

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a node.js script that calls a function that opens a browser using selenium webdriver and navigates to google.com.

This process is perfectly working on my local when I run the app using node app.js.

I have deployed this app on Azure and when I send the request to the api since the server doesn't have any GUI the program doesn't work.

to solve this problem, I want to perform this task on the client side. when the client sends the request to the API a local browser in their computer opens and navigates to Google.

is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can run it on the server-side and present results.  You might consider headless browsers or HTMLUnit if your server has no GUI.  You might also be able to write a browser extension/plugin for this, but not sure why you'd do it that way instead of creating a standalone app that can be installed.  Either way the user would have to install something on their end.

Comment: pcalkins thanks for the solution, but the problem is that I can not move forward with headless browsers, I need the browser to be open then perform some visible actions on the client-side. is there any other solutions?

Comment: The client needs to install an app... the app will extract necessary webdrivers and run them.  (Or run from a server with a GUI, and stream a video of the browser(s) running?)